# Paypal sandbox redirect to homepage for Safari

Tags: paypal

We are having issue with PayPal sandbox. This issue is particular for Safari Browser, which is like below:

1) for first try on safari, when Paypal form submitted, it gets redirected to Paypal home page rather than pay page.
2) Issue issue keeps on occurring, after 4-5 try it gets redirected to correct page. Nothing was changed on code when it works fine.

So is this a known issue with Paypal sandbox or I am missing something?

Comment: I am getting this same issue.  
Have you solved it??

Comment: I am also getting same issue. Any solution?